# Question about symmetry

Tags: geometry, symmetry

[What is the area of the largest trapezoid that can be inscribed in a semi-circle with radius $r=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140339/what-is-the-area-of-the-largest-trapezoid-that-can-be-inscribed-in-a-semi-circle/1140379#comment7783598_1140379)

Here in @Hagen von Eitzen answer He mentioned: "By symmetry alone the largest hexagon that
can be inscribed in a circle is regular hexagon."

What is the meaning of symmetry here? and how to  prove the statement that largest n-gon inscribed in a circle is regular n-gon. I never saw this method before.So I am looking for some references or similar geometry problems like this (for example I think the problem that asks for largest rectangle that can be inscribed in a quarter circle has something to do with symmetry) but I couldn't find anything can you send some links for that? Thank you.

Comment: See all this [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/area-of-largest-circle-inscribe-in-n-sided-regular-polygon/), [here](http://people.math.sc.edu/dilworth/preprints_files/DilworthManeJOGpublished.pdf) and  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon)

Comment: thanks, but first link circle inscribed in regular n-gon

Comment: If you have three adjacent vertices $A,B,C$ and you fix $A$ and $C$ then area of the triangle will be based entirely on the position of $B$ on the circular arch connecting $A$ and $C$.  The maximum triangle will be the triangle with $B$ forming the highest altitude.  That will be when $B$ is on the perpendicular bisector of $AC$.  That so the triangle with greatest area with base $AC$ will be the isosceles one.

Comment: @fleablood So in this problem we divide the n-gon into $n-2$ triangles with no intersection then we maximize the area of each triangle with the method you mentioned then the largest n-gon should be regular one. am I right?

Comment: Well, I suppose hypothetically this argument only shows that no irregular polygon is maximal.  Not that a regular polygon is maximal.  If we actually increased $\triangle ABC$ by nudging $B$ to the right we could simultaneously be decreasing $\triangle BCD$ (although the overall area is growing) and if we adjust each vertices one by one we can get into an infinite loop.

Comment: And it wasn't *my* argument.  It was Hagen von Eitzen's argument in the post you cited.  (which isn't to say I have made the same similar argument in other circumstances.)

Answer (score 3):

I suppose, theoretically, Hagen von Eitzen didn't prove that the largest inscribed $n$-gon is regular, but that for every irregular $n$-gon  the is a larger $n$-gon.  Thus if there is a maximal $n$-gon it must be the regular one.  It is, I suppose, hypothetically possible that no $n$-gon is maximal.  Hagen von Eitzen gave no argument that there is maximal $n$-gon.

The argument that for every irregular $n$-gon there is a larger $n$-gon is like this.

If an $n$-gon is irregular not all the sides are equal and there will be two that unequal and there will be a pair of adjacent unequal sides.  Let this pair of unequal sides be $AB$ between vertices $A,B$ and $BC$ between vertices $A,C$.

These three vertices form a triangle with base $AC$ and the area of this triangle will be $\frac 12 AB\cdot h$ where $h$ is the height of the perpendicular from $B$ to $AC$. Vertices $A$ and $C$ are connected by a circular arch and $B$ is a point on that arch.

If we choose a different point other than $B$ on the arch, say $B'$ then the height of the perpendicular from $B'$ to $AC$ may be a different value and the triangle $\triangle AB'C$ will have a different area than $\triangle ABC$.

The point on the arch that has the greatest perpendicular value is the point that is on the perpendicular bisector of $AC$, let's call it $D$.  As $D$ is on the perpendicular bisector $AD=DC$ and as $AB\ne BC$ we know $B \ne D$ and that the height of the perpendicular from $B$ to $AC$ is less than the height of the perpendicular for $D$ to $AC$.  And therefore the area of $\triangle ABC$ is less than the area of triangle $\triangle ADC$.

ANd so the area of the $n$-gon with vertices $A,B,C$ (and $n-3$ other vertices) will be smaller than the $n$-gon with the same $n-1$ verices but only $B$ replaced with $D$.

So our first inscribe $n$-gon is smaller than another existing inscribed $n$-gon.

Answer (score 2):

Let's ignore the symmetry argument and start as a minimization/maximization problem. Your n-gon inscribed in a circle of radius $1$ has the angles at the center $2\alpha_i$. Then the length of the side is $2\sin\alpha_i$ and the length of the perpendicular to the side is $\cos\alpha_i$. Then the area of the n_gon is $$A=\sum_{i=1}^n\sin\alpha_i\cos\alpha_i,$$
subject to the constraint $$\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i=\pi$$
We rewrite $$A=\frac12 \sum_{i=1}^n\sin(2\alpha_i)$$
Using Lagrange multiplier method:$$\frac{d}{d\alpha_i}\left(\frac12 \sum_{i=1}^n\sin(2\alpha_i)-\lambda(\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i-\pi)\right)=0$$
This results in $$\cos(2\alpha_i)=\lambda$$
So all $\alpha_i$ are the same, therefore you have a regular n-gon.

Comment: "Let's ignore the symmetry argument"  How would that answer the OPs question about symmetry then?

Comment: @fleablood I am not sure that the symmetry argument is a straightforward one. As seen in your answer, you took several steps beside the simple symmetry. In fact, even your justification is valid only to say that if you have a regular n-gon, and you move one vertex, then the area is smaller. You would need to add arguments about why the reasoning would apply if you move multiple vertices simultaneously.

Comment: I agree and a pointed that out in my first paragraph.  But the OP was a question about explaining what an argument by symmetry means... that is the actual *question*....  the question wasn't about how to actually find a maximal polygon... (BTW I never argued an regular polygon is made smaller by any adjustment... I argued an irregular polygon can always be made larger by adjustment.  So no irregular is maximal.  I never claimed a regular polygon is maximal or even that there can't be infinitely more larger irregular ones.)

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for the feedback. I slightly misread both the question and your answer

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a hexagon inscribed in circle. Let's divide the area of hexagon into 6 triangles - with sides as two radii and a side of hexagon. Note that each SIDE of the hexagon has identical contribution to the area. So, to maximise area the best you can do is keep all of them equal.

Comment: Why?  Why would a triangle with a long side and a triangle with a short side overall have less area than two triangles with medium sides?

Comment: I'm not following this argument. In what sense does each side of an irregular hexagon have identical contribution to the area ?

Comment: The area is sum of areas of triangles. (Each triangle area is proportional to sin(angle) it subtends at the center) Say a side subtends greater angle than the other side. What is special in this side that the other side not have? Why keep the area of one triangle greater than the other while in the total area, we are just adding all triangle areas. No triangle area is squared, or scaled in the sum. Then why would I make one or two of the areas larger than the other. Any area can't be larger than the other. So let's make them equal.